# Playing Delayed Sounds In Browser With Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, settimeout

We have a few sales teams. For these sales teams, we have a leaderboard. Each time one of them makes a sale, a sound is played over the speakerphones through a browser which refreshes the page every 2 minutes and checks for differences. Once it sees a difference, it plays the team's sound.

Previously the sounds would slur together because I'd call the function like such:

```
setTimeout(sounds[team_id].play(), delayTime);
```

I figured out that I had to make it a function reference point, by removing (). In that case it seemed I could get no way to send an argument to that reference point.

Tumbling down the rabbit hole later, after browser bugs and accidently mutings, I'm tired of the way I'm doing things. I don't think this is optimal.

I need a good way to play sound files from any location (no, I'm not hotlinking) that don't have to adhere to SetTimeout. I'm thinking something to do with jQuery's delay() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's delay function is based on `setTimeout`, as would be any other delaying or time-based functionality provided by any other library.

I am not seeing why you are having troubles - a closure should be able to handle the situation you describe:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  sounds[team_id].play()
}, delayTime);
```

Assuming that `team_id` is the id of the team who's sound you'd like to play, and that `team_id` is available in the scope from which you call `setTimeout`. Without seeing the full code in context, it is difficult to pinpoint any potential problems.

Comment: I understand, and I can confirm that a sound was being accepted into the browser, but only through various crappy workarounds using hard-coded methods. (as well, I couldn't hear it in the browser) The problem mainly lies in that I'll now be adding the ability for each salesman to have their own sound, and I'm just not hard-coding it. Also it seems that if I do play(), the sounds will all play together, because they need a reference function.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "reference function". Can you post more of your code - specifically the part where `sounds` and `team_id` are defined?